# How to make provide views and specify which users can GET it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created the following model, with an author who is the user that created it and Title and description, with few other fields.

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    #  who_can_see
    who_can_see = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='tweet_user', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

now I want to filter books based on `who_can_see` and `auther`
My question is: how to modify this `books = Book.objects.filter(added_by=user)` in order to get only the posts that have the authenticated username included in the `who_can_see` field.

---

in `models.py` i created this field to add the usernames that can see the view `who_can_see = models.ManyToManyField( settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='tweet_user', blank=True)`, but I don't know how to filter views based on them, also users can see all books even when they are not loggedin

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def add_book(request):
    print({"request.data": request.data})
    payload = request.data
    user = request.user
    try:
        author = Author.objects.get(id=payload["author"])
        book = Book.objects.create(
            title=payload["title"],
            description=payload["description"],
            added_by=user,
            author=author,
            who_can_see=payload["who_can_see"]  # 
        )
        serializer = BookSerializer(book)
        return JsonResponse({'books': serializer.data}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    except Exception:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Something terrible went wrong'}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)


@api_view(["GET"])
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def get_books(request):
# here maybe I need other arguments than request to get the other filed, in order to create if statements.
    user = request.user.id
    # books = Book.objects.filter(added_by=user)
    books = Book.objects.filter(who_can_see=user, added_by=user) #  after i created this user who are not logged in can see the all private books.
    serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)
    return JsonResponse({'books': serializer.data}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: What is the question exactly ?

Comment: how to modify this `books = Book.objects.filter(added_by=user)` in order to get only the posts that have the authenticated username included in the `who_can_see` field

Comment: How you check posts that have the authenticated username? What is parameter for this?

Comment: @MuhammadHassan in `models.py` i created this field to add the usernames that can see the view `who_can_see = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='tweet_user', blank=True)`, but I don't know how to filter views based on them, also users can see all books even when they are not loggedin

Comment: ```books = Book.objects.filter(who_can_see=request.user)``` does not work ?

Comment: it works, but when users logout they are able to see all the books

Comment: But you use ```@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write query in which you have to check for which book current user is in `who_can_see` field. You can write this like this.

```
from django.db.models import Q

current_user = request.user
books = Book.objects.filter(Q(Q(added_by=user) | Q(who_can_see=current_user)))
```

if you want to get books for which `who_can_see` is empty

```
books = Book.objects.filter(Q(Q(added_by=user) | Q(who_can_see=current_user) | Q(who_can_see=None)))
```

Comment: what if I want to make if statements with it like `if who_can_see is empty: 
Book.objects.all()`

Comment: You can use who_can_see=None. Check the updated answer

Comment: that worked very well, thank you, but now when users logout they can see all posts‍♂️

Comment: You can add check this query only run when user is authenticated. Otherwise return empty list.